# Check if a file is checkedout from clearcase

Tags: makefile, clearcase

I have a makefile in which I want to do checkout on a file if this file isn't already checkedout:

```
VAR=$(shell cleartool ls $(HOME)/all_files.tgz | grep CHECKEDOUT)
build:
     @if ["$(VAR)" == ""]; then \
        cleartool co -unres -nc $(HOME)/all_files.tgz;\
     fi
     @ tar czf $(HOME)/all_files.tgz $(OUT)/*.log
```

I get the following error if all_files.tgz is checked out:

```
/bin/sh: [/home/ge/prj/all_files.tgz@@/main/10/CHECKEDOUT from /main/10             Rule: CHECKEDOUT: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the brackets in the shell you MUST include whitespace around them.  This is because `[` is actually a separate command: if you use `["$(VAR)"` that expands to the string you quote above (`[/home/ge/prj/all_files.tgz@@/main/10/CHECKEDOUT from /main/10`) and that is not a valid command name.  Similarly for the final `]`: must have whitespace around it.

Use:

```
VAR=$(shell cleartool ls $(HOME)/all_files.tgz | grep CHECKEDOUT)
build:
        @if [ "$(VAR)" == "" ]; then \
            cleartool co -unres -nc $(HOME)/all_files.tgz;\
        fi
        @ tar czf $(HOME)/all_files.tgz $(OUT)/*.log
```

This is a kind of odd rule though.  Since VAR is just a shell function, and you're using it in the shell, why even bother to use `$(shell ...)`?

Comment: +1. I have been writing too much bash script, and not enough makefile lately.

Comment: Would `ifeq ($(strip $(VAR)),) xxx endif` work too in a Makefile to test if the var is empty?

Comment: Yes, that will work too, if it's OK that the check run up-front, at the time the makefile is parsed.  The example provided by georgiana defers the check so it doesn't happen until much later, when the `build` target recipe is going to be run.  That could be an important difference, or not (we can't tell since we don't have complete information).

Comment: Thanks for your help (worked with a single '=': @if [ "$(VAR)" = "" ];). The variable VAR is defered when the build targetis called.

Comment: Right, missed that... `==` is an extension supported by some shells, like `bash`, but not all.  The POSIX standard operator for equality in the shell test program is `=`.